How to configure null key Jackson serialization in Spring Boot
I would like to object with null keys in map.
I have the following error:
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Cannot invoke "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer.serialize(Object, com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider)" because "keySerializer" is null]

I tried to register Jackson customizer:
    @Bean
    fun jsonCustomizer(): Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer =
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer { builder: Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder ->
            builder.postConfigurer { objectMapper: ObjectMapper ->
                objectMapper
                    .serializerProvider
                    .setNullKeySerializer(
                        object : JsonSerializer<Any>() {
                            override fun serialize(
                                value: Any,
                                gen: JsonGenerator,
                                serializers: SerializerProvider,
                            ) {
                                gen.writeFieldName("")
                            }
                        },
                    )
            }
        }

But it does not have any effect.
Edit:
more detailed error message:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot invoke "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer.serialize(Object, com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider)" because "keySerializer" is null (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.MyOuterFoo["outerFooKey"]->com.example.SecondFoo["secondFooKey"]->java.util.Arrays$ArrayList[0]->com.example.InnerFoo["innerFooKey"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["hashMapKey"])

I think it might be a problem with your dependency versions, or maybe you are importing a wrong class. Please try to create a clean project from https://start.spring.io/ with only the web dependency, then use the following TestController and run GET http://localhost:8080/test, it just works:


Remember that in Kotlin, you must use ? to indicate that a variable can hold a null value. Therefore, you must add ? to the type of the value parameter to allow for nullable values:
                                value: Any?,

Try this on a clean project: GET http://localhost:8080/test
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    fun test(): Map<Any?, Any?> {
        val response = HashMap<Any?, Any?>()
        response.put("hello", "world")
        response.put(null, "test")
        return response
    }

    @Bean
    fun jsonCustomizer(): Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer =
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer { builder: Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder ->
            builder.postConfigurer { objectMapper: ObjectMapper ->
                objectMapper.serializerProvider.setNullKeySerializer(
                    object : JsonSerializer<Any>() {
                        override fun serialize(value: Any?, gen: JsonGenerator, serializers: SerializerProvider) {
                            gen.writeFieldName("")
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }

}

In addition, you can also customize the ObjectMapper itself:
    @Autowired
    fun objectMapperCustomizer(objectMapper: ObjectMapper) {
        objectMapper.serializerProvider.setNullKeySerializer(
            object : JsonSerializer<Any>() {
                override fun serialize(value: Any?, gen: JsonGenerator, serializers: SerializerProvider) {
                    gen.writeFieldName("")
                }
            }
        )
    }


I use the same logic in the Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder. postConfigurer`, but somehow, it does not get picked up.

@pixel Have you tried adding ? to the type of the value parameter in serialize? I edited my answer, please try these two options, they work for me.

I tried it with no luck. However, I managed to obtain a more detailed error message.

@pixel I edited my answer to add the imports of the class. I think it might be a problem with your dependency versions, or maybe you are importing a wrong class. Please try to create a clean project from https://start.spring.io/ with only the web dependency, then use this TestController and run GET http://localhost:8080/test. I just tested it and it works (see attached image).

I found the root cause and came with workaround. I have data class that contains two fields, one Long and the second is a Value class @JvmInline value class Foo(     val properties: Map<String, Any>, ) and this value class is causing the issue. I changed it to data class, and it works, but I wonder how value classes can be serialized...

@pixel I'm not really sure. I think you should create a new question just for this.

@pixel Do you need any more help with this particular question?
